# Use of selectionArgs not giving expected results

Tags: android, sql

I've gotten very comfortable with SQL over the last couple of years... but this particular scenario has me pretty stumped.

In short, how could this:

```
int totalMinutes = (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60) + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

Cursor timeCheck = mDatabase.query("dailys", null, "dueToday = 1 and occursAtTime = 1 and (minutesOfDay + snoozeDelay) < " + totalMinutes + " and completed = 0 and stopRemindingToday = 0", null, null, null, null);
```

and this:

```
int totalMinutes = (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60) + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

String [] totalMinutesToday = {Integer.toString(totalMinutes)};

Cursor timeCheck = mDatabase.query("dailys", null, "dueToday = 1 and occursAtTime = 1 and (minutesOfDay + snoozeDelay) < ? and completed = 0 and stopRemindingToday = 0", totalMinutesToday, null, null, null);
```

give different results? minutesOfDay and snoozeDelay are both Integer types and to my knowledge, I've never had a situation like this come up in the past. The second example returns one result that, after very carefully checking the data for each column, should absolutely not be a valid result. minutesOfDay + snoozeDelay is 660, and at the time of testing this, the variable totalMinutes (when using simple android logging) was between 490 and 500.

To clarify, the first example returns no results and that is what is expected based on the data.

EDIT

I did a little research on posts here and this apparently also works:

```
int totalMinutes = (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60) + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

String [] totalMinutesToday = {Integer.toString(totalMinutes)};

Cursor timeCheck = mDatabase.query("dailys", null, "dueToday = 1 and occursAtTime = 1 and (minutesOfDay + snoozeDelay) < CAST(? AS INTEGER) and completed = 0 and stopRemindingToday = 0", totalMinutesToday, null, null, null);
```

Still wondering why this is necessary. I don't recall ever having to do this for integer values passed through selection arguments before. Is the value that is being past being converted to having single quotes around it?